# Expected value of two sums

Tags: statistics, summation, parameter-estimation

I am trying to derive the expected value of the following form:

$E[{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} {x_i}{y_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} {x_i}^2}}] = $

I understand that x is a constant, and that y is a random variable. I believe the trouble I am having involves some unfamiliarity with manipulating sums. What property should I try to apply to manipulate this to something manageable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) to justify the following steps.
$$E \left[\frac{\sum_i x_i y_i}{\sum_i x_i^2}\right] = \frac{E \left[\sum_i x_i y_i\right]}{\sum_i x_i^2} = \frac{\sum_i x_i E[y_i]}{\sum_i x_i^2}.$$
Use your model assumptions to compute $E[y_i]$.

Comment: Am I allowed to do the following with variance? My biggest concern would be pulling the sum of x*y out of the variance:
$Var(\hat{\beta_1}) = Var({\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} {x_i}{y_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} {x_i}^2}}) = \frac{1}{{({\sum_{i=1}^{n} {x_i}^2})}^2}*Var({\sum_{i=1}^{n} {x_i}{y_i}}) = \frac{{\sum_{i=1}^{n} {x_i}^2}}{{({\sum_{i=1}^{n} {x_i}^2})}^2}*Var({{y_i}}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{{\sum_{i=1}^{n} {x_i}^2}}$